# How to disable service creation from helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am just doing one POC on basic helm chart installation on my Google Kubernetes engine. When I create a new helm chart it creates certain files and folder structure automatically. Now my requirement is to create only the deployment & Pod. not the kubernetes service. Is there any way to avoid kubernetes service creation? For Ingress I can see `enabled: false` property but for service it does not work.

Comment: Is this a public Helm chart you are using?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think it is public helm chart only. It was pre-installed on GCP

Comment: what is the chart name?

Comment: Just any chart, say test-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just delete service YAML file from templates. That will work.

Comment: this might be an alternative. Helm has a conditional templating. This can be achieve by wrapping the entire content within if condition. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878852/4540216

Answer (score 4):

[`helm create chart`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/5859403fd92bfb319ae865fcc2466701607da334/docs/helm/helm_create.md#helm-create) command by default creates you below file hierarchy:

```
chart/
  |
  |- .helmignore        # Contains patterns to ignore when packaging Helm charts.
  |
  |- Chart.yaml         # Information about your chart
  |
  |- values.yaml        # The default values for your templates
  |
  |- charts/            # Charts that this chart depends on
  |
  |- templates/         # The template files
  |
  |- templates/tests/   # The test files
```

So yes, you can delete unnecessary for you objects from `chart/templates` directory to avoid creation them during `helm install`

Github source code that is responsible to create a chart directory along with the common files and directories used in a chart
https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/5859403fd92bfb319ae865fcc2466701607da334/cmd/helm/create.go