# Helm Conditional Templates

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I found that we can create subcharts and conditionally include them as described here: [Helm conditionally install subchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032974/helm-conditionally-install-subchart)

I have just one template that I want conditionally include in my chart but I could not find anything in the docs. Is there such feature?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I discovered that empty templates are not loaded. I solved it by wrapping my yaml file content in an `if` condition.

```
{{ if .Values.something }}
content of yaml file
{{ end }}
```

Comment: How would I check if a Variable is Null. For instance, how can I create a Template only if a variable `.Values.something` is Null

Comment: According to [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/), _a pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is a nil (empty or null)_ @Kiran

Comment: When I use this aproach with a secret, it deletes the secret on upgrade

Answer (score 36):

You simply wrap the template resource at the first and last lines with the check you want to do. Let's take the official Grafana chart as example:

In its `values.yaml`, it has a [flag](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/40f5546a9ed29c09ae512dacea103afb2a96a445/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L108-L109) called `ingress.enabled`, which looks like the following:

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: false
```

Then in [its ingress template resource](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/40f5546a9ed29c09ae512dacea103afb2a96a445/stable/grafana/templates/ingress.yaml#L1), this flag is checked:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
...
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
...
{{- end }}
```

As a result, ingress object will only be created if `ingress.enabled` is set to true.